# How to save python list structure when importing from excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have excel file with a column like this

```
 [{'accident_number': '330002530', 'accident_date_time': '07.02.2017 11:06', 'accident_type': 'Столкновение', 'accident_place': 'Кировская область, Слободской район, Слободской', 'damage_points': ['01', '08'], 'vehicle_damage_state': 'Повреждено'}, {'accident_number': '330008496', 'accident_date_time': '23.08.2021 12:19', 'accident_type': 'Наезд на стоящее ТС', 'accident_place': 'Кировская область, Слободской район, Слободской', 'damage_points': ['117', '118'], 'vehicle_damage_state': 'Повреждено'}]
```

It's a list of dicts. When i'm importing this to pandas dataframe with `pd.read_excel`, i see it has type string. The question is how can i make python understand it's a list of dicts?

I thought maybe there's a way to create a new list variable and assign it to the contents of my excel column but cant find a way to do it. I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: as it is a string, you would have to use `split()` and work on each component to recreate the list of dicts.  The alternative would be to format the excel sheet appropriately...

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
[{"a": 1}, {"b": 2}] # Your string in txt

file = open("dictionary_string.txt", "r")
contents = file.read()
dictionary = ast.literal_eval(contents)
file.close()

print(type(dictionary)) # Output <class 'dict'>
print(dictionary) # Output [{"a": 1}, {"b": 2}]
```

The other option is save the file as json:

```
import json
  
# Opening JSON file
f = open('data.json')
  
data = json.load(f)
  
for i in data['some_column']:
    print(i)
  
# Closing file
f.close()
```